# How to implement constraints for 1 image between 2 label for storyboard file

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I had an imageView and 2 labels in the custom cell of the collection and how can I set the constraints for the images and labels. I need to center the 2 labels of the imageView at the same time I need to extend the label width at the run time. If the left side label had lengthy name I will just it to the center. Please help me.

[image: See image]

Comment: I would really like to help you, but I did not understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: If the left side label had lengthy name I will just it to the center. what do you mean by this ?

Comment: left side label had lengthy name i will adjust center to the image. this  what i want

Comment: i need to center the 2 labels and the image.

Comment: Your question is not clear. And _I need to center 2 labels and the image_ is not helpful. You need to tell every item's position in all cases. It will be better if you can show the output that you want by positioning them in the storyboard. Only then others can help you achieve that.

Comment: @SriSampath - To clarify, show a couple more images... How should it look if both labels have short text? If one label is long and the other is short? What about if the text of the labels is too long to fit for the image view's width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably need `UIStackView` with distribution set to `Fill Equally`

[image: StackView]